# Rails Tutorial User.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Michael Hartl's tutorial (chapter 6). When I try to create a new user in the rails console:

```
user = User.new(name: "Lord of Darkness", email: "LoD@hell.com")
```

I get:

```
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Lord of Darkness", email: "LoD@hell.com",
 created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
```

Which seem to be correct. But when I try to save I get this:

```
irb(main):007:0> user.save
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mUser Exists (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("us
  ers"."email") = LOWER('mhartl@example.com') LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mrollback transaction←[0m
  => false
```

which definitely is not what I want. My user_spec is passing all tests.
My *user.rb* looks like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
             uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

**What causes this save problem?** Without solving this error I cannot go on with the tutorial.

Comment: checkout user.valid? or not it seems to be email id is exist,checkout user.errors.messages or full_messages,

Comment: I think it is *User.create()* not *User.save()*

Comment: check for validations errors as suggested by @Amar, u should be be able to track it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your error is stemming from the fact that the `User` you are creating doesn't have a password.

Your `User` model validates a password and requires its presence, but when you create new a `User` from the command line, he/she doesn't have a password yet.

Comment: You're right. Problem lies in fact that in user definition I forgot to enter password and password confirmation. Thank you very much!